# In python, How to give an alphabet, the value of the next alphabet?

Tags: python

I just started learning python 2 days ago and I am trying to make a cipher. In it the alphabet is given the value of the next alphabet. for example, if you want to print "b" you need to type "a", and so on. I have already done it manually and here's the result.
I just want to ask, is there any easier way to do this?

#output: hello

```
a = 'b'
b = 'c'
c = 'd'
d = 'e'
e = 'f'
f = 'g'
g = 'h'
h = 'i'
i = 'j'
j = 'k'
k = 'l'
l = 'm'
m = 'n'
n = 'o'
o = 'p'
p = 'q'
q = 'r'
r = 's'
s = 't'
t = 'u'
u = 'v'
v = 'w'
w = 'x'
x = 'y'
y = 'z'
z = 'a'

print(f'{g}{d}{k}{k}{n}');
```

Comment: An alphabet is a *collection* of alphabetic characters, not an individual character itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Iterate a string wich contains the alphabet:

```
alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
#if you want to print "b" you need to type "a"
def print_alph(char):
    for i in range(len(alph)):
        if alph[i] == char.upper():
            print(alph[0]) if char.upper() == 'Z' else print(alph[i+1])

print_alph('A')
print_alph('z')
```

Output:

```
B
A
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Even though I don't know what most of it means, but surely I will start making some sense of it in a day or so. Thank you!

Comment: Basically you want to Iterate the string and this will always check the `i` element of `alph` with  `if alph[i] == char.upper():` looking for `char` inside the string and if the statement is true we need to check if the char is `Z` so it can print the first element wich is `A` if char is not `Z` it should print the next letter of the alphabet. Also we use .upper() to avoid problems with lowercase characters since  `'z' != 'Z'`

Answer (score 1):

The `str` type has a built-in translation mechanism.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
>>> d = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[1:] + alphabet)
>>> "gdkkn".translate(d)
'hello'
```

`maketrans` can take two arguments of equal length, and constructs a table matching corresponding characters in each argument to each other.

Answer (score -2):

I think you this function works for you.

```
def next_alpha(s: str):
    return chr((ord(s.upper()) + 1 - 65) % 26 + 65).lower()
```

Comment: way too many magic numbers. All you have to do is use `.index + 1` then `% len(alphabet)`